# How to insert NULL into decimal type column using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert `NULL` into a column, called `price`, which is of type `Decimal`.

The column is nullable and the default is `NULL`. I want to insert `NULL`, only when nothing has been entered in the "price" input on a HTML form. This is my PHP code:

```
$item_name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
$price = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['price']);

$con->query("INSERT INTO items (item_name,price) VALUES ('$item_name','$price')");
```

With the above code, when I leave the "price" input empty, `0.00` is inserted into the database.

I am pretty sure that, when the "price" input field is left empty, `$price` is `NULL` because I tried:

```
if ($price == NULL) {
  $price == 4;
}
```

and `4.00` was inserted into the database.

I also tried:

```
$con->query("INSERT INTO items (item_name,price) VALUES ('$item_name',NULL)");
```

and `NULL` was inserted into the database.

How do I insert `NULL` into `price` when `$price` is `NULL`?

Comment: @EdBangga Thank you. I had a look at the answers to this question but I have tried declaring ```$price = NULL``` and ```0.00``` is still inserted into the database.

Comment: use ('$item_name',NULLIF('$price', ''))");

Comment: @EdBangga Thank you very much. This worked with the removal of one ")". If you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept it as the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to insert null in your price column.

```
$con->query("INSERT INTO items (item_name,price) VALUES ('$item_name',NULLIF('$price', ''))");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all stop using `real_escape_string`. You should be using prepared statements instead. It will help you solve your problem!

Here is how it should be done properly:

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$price = $_POST['price'] ?: null; // make the value null if it is empty
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO items (item_name,price) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $item_name, $price);
$stmt->execute();
```

`?:` operator can be used in PHP to specify a default value if the variable is empty.

Answer (score -1):

you must use blank, not null, if you want the default value to be null.

one example:

eg: mysql_query("INSERT INTO number1,number2 VALUES(NULL,1)");